# Open Link in Safari from loaded page in Webview

Tags: javascript, html, ios

Im wondering how to open Link in Safari instead load in webview. i tried few ways,

```
    function openpage()
{
system.openURL ( "http://www.worldwildlife.org/gift-center/gifts/Species-Adoptions/Panda.aspx", "_blank" )
}
```

or `window.open`, `target _blank` nothing works.
Any ideas? it could be html or JS/JQ, the point is to set button to open URL in safari insted of loading in uiwebview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the app displaying the UIWebView this iOS snippet will direct all links in the UIWebView to open in Mobile Safari.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if (inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```